# Alternating orientation of 2-gang receptacles within same box

Tags: receptacle, mounting

Has anyone ever mounted receptacles in opposite directions in the same 2-gang box such that the hot sides faced each other and the neutrals faced outward?  Seems to me this would reduce the chances of a short or arcing.

Comment: There is zero chance of "a short or arcing" unless manipulating the devices in the box while hot. Such work should not be done hot in almost all circumstances.

Comment: "Has anyone ever...?" isn't a good question for this site. What are _actually_ trying to find out? If you're asking about the safety aspect, revise to do so. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Just use a built-to purpose quad receptacle, (not two duplexes in one box) which are available pointing all 4 ways (the advantage is that you can plug in 4 power bricks unless they are abnormally huge ones.)

Comment: Isherwood--I had never heard it brought up, so I wondered about it.  I don't think that's a crime, especially since there's nowhere else to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from aesthetics, it would be confusing. Think USB, where somehow [it always takes three tries to get it right](https://www.howtogeek.com/713525/the-usb-paradox-why-do-usb-connections-need-three-tries/). Normally within a building, or at least in a room, all receptacles face the same direction. That works with muscle memory so that you can almost always plug things in correctly the first time without looking closely.

If a box of 4 receptacles has two one way and two the other way, you will have to spend 2 seconds extra thinking/looking each time to get it right. Not a big deal in the grand scheme of things, but a totally unnecessary annoyance.

In addition, if one receptacle in each pair has GFCI then things may get a little extra confusing. And if they are on two separate circuits (or two halves on an MWBC) then you **really** don't want those hots near each other.

Answer (score 4):

People would dislike the aesthetics.  Might as well just wrap the terminals with tape if that's the concern. I know some consider it an amateur move but I don't.

Comment: Thank you very much to all who answered.  I'll just do it normally.